# Why does MSIEXEC fail to remove during a /X?

Tags: windows-installer, uninstallation

We have an installed application (MSI), and we try to remove it using the following command line option:

```
MsiExec.exe /x{code} /qn /liwearucmopvx+ C:\Log\UnInstall.tra
```

However sometimes (no clue why) it generates the following errors:

```
MSI (s) (BC:F8) [02:02:50:031]: Note: 1: 1725 
MSI (s) (BC:F8) [02:02:50:031]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (BC:F8) [02:02:50:031]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (BC:F8) [02:02:50:031]: Product: Application -- Removal failed.
```

What do these mean?

Comment: The command line should be msiexec.exe /x {GUID}.

Answer (score 2):

From experience I'd say this is a **custom action** conditioned to run only on uninstall triggering an error and hence causing the uninstall to roll back. The result is a product that is impossible to uninstall, until the error is resolved. Great work Microsoft!

What product is this uninstall for? The cleanest way to solve an uninstall problem like this is to create a minor upgrade for the installed product and optionally wrap and install it as a patch. This will re-cache a new MSI file on the system where you have resolved the error in the uninstall sequence. This new, cached MSI is then used for uninstall. This is time consuming and difficult work requiring significant QA efforts, and is generally only done when absolutely necessary.

<del>Other options include using **MsiZap** to rip out the MSI registration of the product. This will leave files and registry junk on the system, but the product will no longer be registered.</del> *(msizap is outdated, deprecated and unsupported. Don't use it - there are too many incompatibilities with newer Windows versions. Perhaps try [**this support tool**](http://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;290301) instead)*.

If you provide some more information this should be solvable without too much hassle. You might want to run that log file through a tool to look for other errors while you are at it. Microsoft provides the **WiLogUtl.exe** utility for this purpose. It is only available in the [**Microsoft SDK**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_SDK), which is a whopping download.

Answer (score 1):

Something's not being found.  According to errlook.exe:

- Error 3 is the Win32 error "The system cannot find the path specified."
- -2147287038 is the HRESULT for "%1 could not be found."

A utility like [SysInternals' Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) might help you figure out the thing not being found (or maybe it's in another nearby MSI log message).